# val_loss did not improve from inf + loss:nan Error while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-3.8

I have a problem that occurs when I start training my model.
This error says that val_loss did not improve from inf and loss: nan.
At the beginning I thought it was because of the learning rate but now I'am not sure what it is because I've tried ceveral different learning rates and none of those worked for me.
I hope that someone can help me.

**My preferences**
optimizer = adam,
learning rate = 0.01
(I've already tried a bunch of different learning rates for example: 0.0005, 0.001, 0.00146,0.005,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8 but none of these worked for me)
EarlyStopping = enabled
(Training is stopping because of the EarlyStopping at epoch 3 because there is no improvement. I've also disabled EarlyStopping every time the model stopped the training at epoch 3 and let it make 100 epochs without EarlyStopping enabled.)
ReduceLR = disabled

**On what I try to train my model**
I try to train this model on my gpu (EVGA RTX 3080 FTW3 ULTRA)

```
model = Sequential()


model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding='same',kernel_initializer='he_normal',input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols,1)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding='same',kernel_initializer='he_normal',input_shape=(img_rows,img_cols,1)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))


model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='same',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='same',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))


model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),padding='same',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),padding='same',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))


model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3),padding='same',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3),padding='same',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64,kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))


model.add(Dense(64,kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))


model.add(Dense(num_classes,kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))


print(model.summary())


from keras.optimizers import RMSprop,SGD,Adam
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint,EarlyStopping,ReduceLROnPlateau 


checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('Wave.h5',
                             monitor='val_loss',
                             mode='min',
                             save_best_only=True,
                             verbose=1)


earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                              min_delta=0,
                              patience=3,
                              verbose=1,
                              restore_best_weights=True)


'''reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',
                              factor=0.2,
                              patience=3,
                              verbose=1,
                              min_delta=0.0001)'''


callbacks = [earlystop,checkpoint] #reduce_lr


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer= Adam(lr=0.01),   
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code, or at least the relevant parts if you know which is?

Comment: sure I'll provide it in my question section

Comment: Are you using `AMD Graphics Card`

Comment: no I using an nvidia rtx 3080

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue for me who had the same problem. The issue was that I had nan/inf-values in my train/val-set. These values were created for some specific datasets by the `df.pct_change()` function.

If you are normalizing your values, make sure that the bounds that are used to normalize the values are not nan/inf.

Comment: Can confirm NaN values the validation data will cause the model to not be able to score the validation, making training a mess.

Answer (score 1):

*Few Comments...*

In these kind of situation, the most preferable is the trial and error approach. It seems like your parameters have diverged while training. Lots of possibilities could be the issue. Also, it seems like you are regularizing your network as well (dropouts, BatchNorm, etc)

#### Suggestions:

- **Normalize** your input data before feeding into the network
- **Comment out/remove** all the dropouts (regularization)/kernel_initializer(use default initialization)/Early stopping etc that you're using from your preference, and let the network be a plain CNN network with just conv layer, pooling, batchnorm, and dense layer. If you see improvements, **then start uncommenting one by one** and you'll understand what was causing the problem.
- Try using **larger units in the dense layer** like 1000 for example, as the dense layer extracts everything (features of the image) the CNN layers have compressed.

Comment: Hello I tried everything but nothing worked for me do you have any other ways I could try to solve my problem?

Comment: That's a bummer. I would have loved to go through the code myself If you had provided any colab link.

Comment: @NoName I have the same problem. Is your loss function customized? Could solve your problem?

Comment: @Marlon Teixeira yes I solved it it was because Cuda was not installed the right way. I fixed it by just watching a tutorial and reinstalling Cuda the correct way. Hope I could help

Comment: @NoName is there any way of testing this hypothesis? Or did you find it by trial and error?