# "val_loss" didn't improved from inf, but loss decreases nicely

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, loss-function, inf

I'm training a Keras model with a custom function, which I have already teste successfully before. Recently, I'm training it with a new dataset and I've got a strange result: The model trains fine but the `val_loss` gives `nan`.
Here is the loss:

```
def Loss(y_true,y_pred):
    y_pred = relu(y_pred)
    z = k.maximum(y_true, y_pred)
    y_pred_negativo = Lambda(lambda x: -x)(y_pred)
    w = k.abs(add([y_true, y_pred_negativo])) 
    if k.sum(z) == 0:
        error = 0
    elif k.sum(y_true) == 0 and k.sum(z) != 0:
        error = 100
    elif k.sum(y_true) == 0 and k.sum(z) == 0:
        error = 0
    else:
        error = (k.sum(w)/k.sum(z))*100
    return error
```

I have tried many things:

1. Looked at the data for NaNs
2. Normalization - on and off
3. Clipping - on and off
4. Dropouts - on and off

Someone told me [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65545918/val-loss-did-not-improve-from-inf-lossnan-error-while-training/65548138?noredirect=1#comment118469550_65548138) it could be a problem with CUDA installation, but I'm not sure.

Any idea about what is the problem or how I can diagnosis it?

Comment: what i think from what you wrote is that theres a sample in the new validation dataset that gives the strange result, what i will try is to do a test: use the validation dataset as training dataset (with no validation) and see if after a specific sample the loss becomes nan

Comment: @BestDogeStackoverflow it is a real mystery. I have done everything I could. I have to look at the y_pred and y_true values, because the another loss measures validates it without problem.

Comment: @BestDogeStackoverflow I'm printing the error value from the loss function and I can see that many values are nan. However, I have to find out why...

Comment: @BestDogeStackoverflow I've found the problem. I'm using a simple conditional for a keras tensor, as so, it is not applying and it is making a division by zero. I have to rewrite that as keras conditional.

Comment: seems you got lucky with the first dataset :D, mark the question  as answered when you can

Comment: @BestDogeStackoverflow first I have to rewrite this condicional in terms of Keras. Then I'll answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be division per zero, but the reason why it was taking place was a little tricky. As you can see, the above definition has some conditionals which were supposed to preclude division per zero. However, they were written to handle NumPy objects and not tensors, which are the objects passed by the Keras methods. Therefore, they were never taking place, and division per zero was happening very often.

In order to fix it, I had to rewrite the Loss in terms of Keras conditionals - remind, avoiding to mix pure Keras with tf.keras - just as I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67047743/how-to-write-a-conditional-with-many-conditions-using-keras). Any further comment is more than welcomed!

Comment: @BestDogeStackoverflow check it out!